# HikariCP auto reconnect

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hikaricp, dbconnection

I use jpa+hibernate+hikariCP. Today I got connection closed error. I setted `connectionTimeout` and `ideleTimeout` properties(hikari). If in meantime use does not do any operition hikari close the pool connections auto. So that I got closed connection problem. My question how can I set properly hiker(jpa,hibernate) properties so if user comes back after 3-4 hours and try to do some operation hikari auto reconnect to db? is it possible?
I use hikari v2.6.1 and hibernate v5.2.8.Final

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should already be working.  Are you holding the connection open during this time?  By default HikariCP closes and renews connections every 30 minutes (maxLifetime default).  If your database has a shorter idle timeout than that, then you need to adjust the setting in HikariCP to match.