# Java Spring Boot connection pool can't reconnect to DB when it restarts

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I currently have an issue with our java spring boot application where the tomcat connection pool can't reconnect to the mysql DB when it goes down. Our current process is to restart the application once the DB is back up or else the app never reconnects to the DB.

This is our current tomcat config:

```
internal.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/table?autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10
internal.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

internal.datasource.jmx-enabled=true
internal.datasource.tomcat.defaultAutoCommit=false

# Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool properties
internal.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=5
internal.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=5
internal.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
internal.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=10
internal.datasource.tomcat.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=600
internal.datasource.tomcat.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=3000
internal.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=15000
internal.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
internal.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
internal.datasource.tomcat.remove-abandoned=true
internal.datasource.tomcat.remove-abandoned-timeout=60
internal.datasource.tomcat.test-while-idle=true
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet successfully received from the server was 32,388,217 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1 milliseconds ago.
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.handleExistingTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:433)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:353)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:463)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy189.createInventoryJob(Unknown Source)
    at com.att.eg.heads.ads.assist.bdms.etl.service.InventoryServiceImpl.generateInventoryCsvs(InventoryServiceImpl.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor261.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:283)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy201.generateInventoryCsvs(Unknown Source)
    at com.att.eg.heads.ads.assist.bdms.etl.service.job.Scheduler.performInventoryJob(Scheduler.java:66)
    at com.att.eg.heads.ads.assist.bdms.etl.service.job.Scheduler$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e2dddb94.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet successfully received from the server was 32,388,217 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1 milliseconds ago.
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1700)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:48)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:189)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet successfully received from the server was 32,388,217 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3517)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3417)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2675)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4776)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor216.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy161.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.jdbc.TracingConnection.setAutoCommit(TracingConnection.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.begin(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1512)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:45)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2969)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3427)
    ... 53 common frames omitted
```

Not sure if I'm missing a configuration or if it is a limitation but any ideas are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do any of the comments or answers of this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58917381/spring-boot-reconnect-to-a-database-after-its-restart

Comment: @jeffrey.d.m tomcat doesnt have a setMaxLifeTime. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html. I did you maxAge as the documentation had similar functionalities but it didn't work.

Comment: @JasonApinchapong - Did you manage to resolve this issue as I am also getting similar problems.